# how to round ALL borders with CSS

Tags: css

instead of putting "border-radius: 10px;" for every single element, is there a way to make all borders rounded?

I'm new to programming so I'm not sure what to try. I'm also using this for something kind of stupid so I don't really wanna put in a ton of effort to learn the language and figure it out lol

Comment: If you want target *all* elements you can use `* { border-radius: 10px; }`, but it is highly unlikely that this is what you want. Just define a class, e.g. `rounder-border` and assign the elements the correct class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as

```css
*{
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The `*` selector is used to select all elements and apply styling on them. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.php) and about selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).